# LeadTool can support real time video broadcasting over internet(Using Web browsers)

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, leadtools-sdk

I want to develop new real time(like camera, any other video source) video broadcasting application. Leadtool also have Streaming Module, can I use Streaming Module of Leadtool for my development?

Please suggest me feasibility and advantages and disadvantages Streaming Module of Leadtool over WebRTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use LEADTOOLS Media Streaming Server with a capture device. Although the streaming server takes the video data from a disk folder, you can capture from a camera to MPEG2-TS DVR file using our Capture control and at the same time use this file as the source for your streaming.

Please note that the LEADTOOLS Video Streaming module supports multiple streaming formats. The Media Streaming Server specifically will provide the support necessary to view video within any browser.

We don't have the comparison information you asked for, but you can try to run your own tests by downloading the free evaluation edition from our website. If you run into problems or need details about implementing the streaming or the client-side web code, contact us through email or our chat service.